# gradle script to build another gradle first

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle, gitlab-ci, pipeline

I am not sure if this is duplicate but i couldnt find similar question.

I have a build.gradle file in the MainApp. which has dependencies on another project. Currently look like the below.

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':TestAPI')
...
}
```

the TestAPI itself is another project, and it includes its own build.gradle file. How Can i make the MainApp's build.gradle to call the TestAPI build.gradle first and then use the output jar file as its own dependency?

You might ask why I want to do this. because each of these projects are an individual repository in the gitlab, and I do have CICD pipeline, when I trigger the MainApp pipeline, I want it to compile the TestAPP pipeline first and use its jar as dependency and then proceed with MainApp pipeline.

Any hints or suggestion is highly appreciate.

Comment: Sounds complicated. Could you build the dependency separately and store it in some artifact repository like artifactory, and then the main project could pull it in via normal Gradle dependencies? Not sure if Gradle's [multi-project builds](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/intro_multi_project_builds.html) work across repository boundaries.

Comment: @Robert, thats kind of solutions that I dont want to do. I want the repo A in gitlab pipeline to access Repo B pipleline, execute it and then use its output as dependency for its own gradle build

Answer (score 0):

@Emily Wong try see this link

https://stackoverflow.com/a/69660601/7505687

I think you could work with multi-modules in gradle and build `MainApp` and gradle will build and include `TestAPI` module naturally.

Note: check if `MainApp` are including all dependencies into final jar ( gradle modules and other implementation dependencies )

Eg. if you need create a `MainApp.jar` with all dependencies as a fatJar try to add this task in `MainApp/build.gradle`

```
 jar {
      // if you have main class
      manifest {
          attributes "Main-Class": "${mainClassName}"
      }

      duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE 

      from { configurations.compileClasspath.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
  }
```