# How to package gradle multi-module spring boot app for other project to use?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, gradle

I have a gradle spring boot project with multiple modules and want to build it as a jar file so that I can reuse the methods from different modules in other projects.

I used `java-library` plugin in the `build.gradle` of the root path and packaged it as a jar. But when I imported it into my other applications as a dependency, the jar files of each module under `BOOT-INF/libs` are not accessible and the methods I called can't be located.

Is there any way I can make each module reusable for other applications?

Answer (score 0):

You can manage projects as module and use them on importing

Check this link:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/69660601/7505687

If you need to share spring boot beans ammong them use `@ComponentScan`