# call dependency jar from gradle task

Tags: gradle

We have the current build.gradle.kts working:

```
plugins {
  id("org.springframework.boot") version "3.1.1"
  id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.1.0"

  id("io.gitlab.arturbosch.detekt") version "1.23.0"

  kotlin("jvm") version "1.8.22"
  kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.8.22"
  jacoco
}

dependencies {
  detektPlugins("io.gitlab.arturbosch.detekt:detekt-formatting:1.23.0")

 // ...
}

task("detektStaged", JavaExec::class) {
  mainClass.set("io.gitlab.arturbosch.detekt.cli.Main")
  description = "Run Kotlin static analysis on staged files."
  group = "verification"
  classpath = files(configurations.detekt)

  doFirst {
    println("Running detekt check on staged files...")
    var stagedFilesList = getStagedFiles()
    var excludedFilesList = ""
    // ...
    val reportDir = "${buildDir}/reports/detekt"
    val params = listOf(
      "--input", stagedFilesList,
      "--excludes", excludedFilesList,
      "--config", "$rootDir/detekt/detekt.yml",
      "--build-upon-default-config",
      "--baseline", "$rootDir/detekt/detekt-baseline.xml",
      "--plugins", "$rootDir/detekt/detekt-formatting-1.23.0.jar", // <----
      "--report", "html:$reportDir/report.html",
    )
    args(params)
  }
}
```

At the very bottom it uses `"--plugins", "$rootDir/detekt/detekt-formatting-1.23.0.jar"`. This jar is currently committed to source control, which I don't like. I wonder if we could just refer to the jar from the project dependencies, but don't understand how?

Comment: If they are in the same repo/dir structure (always, guaranteed), have you looked into using a multi project gradle build?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69660071/multiple-projects-within-one-gradle-project  Also, Gradle docs here:  https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html